# GeoNear Query giving error unable to find index for $geoNear query"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a POC on geonear queries but i am getting

```
 Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=zircon.storeTree: GEONEAR  field=start maxdist=0.045045 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query",
    "code" : 2
```

I have created my basic indexes as well.

```
> db.store.getIndexes();                                   
        [                                                          
                {                                                  
                        "v" : 1,                                   
                        "key" : {                                  
                                "_id" : 1                          
                        },                                         
                        "name" : "_id_",                           
                        "ns" : "zircon.store"                      
                },                                                 
                {                                                  
                        "v" : 1,                                   
                        "key" : {                                  
                                "point" : "2dsphere"               
                        },                                         
                        "name" : "point_2dsphere",                 
                        "ns" : "zircon.store",                     
                        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3                 
                },                                                 
                {                                                  
                        "v" : 1,                                   
                        "key" : {                                  
                                "location.Point" : "2dsphere"      
                        },                                         
                        "name" : "location.Point_2dsphere",        
                        "ns" : "zircon.store",                     
                        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3                 
                }                                                  
        ]
```

My model is

````
```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b4d4437ab5db070e8cc02d"),
  "location": {
    "Point": {
      "x": 47.629104999999996,
      "y": 77.21983919
    }
  },
  "name": "Gulati XX :19",
  "createdDate": ISODate("2016-08-17T21:16:51.605Z"),
  "modifiedDate": ISODate("2016-08-17T21:16:51.605Z")
}
```
````

Kindly suggest on what i am doing wrong here.. What is causing the geonear still not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, and the problem was that i created my index on my "location.coordinates" field instead of on the "location" field. This worked fine in my meteor development server but once pushed to staging server the db could not find the index.

When creating a 2dspere index you should use the "compound" method and do it on the parrent location field as per the mongo docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#id1

Given your json file and db name i would try the following: db.store.createIndex({"location": "2dspere"})
or
db.store.ensureIndex({"location": "2dspere"})

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide index for the location value.

*example:*

```
{ location : { $near : [ -73.9667, 40.78 ], $maxDistance: 0.10 } }
```